# Have internet calendar events show to other Exchange users

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, google-calendar

I have an Exchange mailbox with a standard calendar where other users can see busy/free status.

I also have a Google Calendar that I've added as an Internet calendar that I use for tracking personal events.

I'd like other users to see my free/busy status with these appointments, but when they look at my schedule, only events in my main Exchange calendar show this.

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: Google discontinued support for the plug-in that supported syncing your Google Calendar to your Exchange calendar.  I am sure there is an add-on that exist though.

Comment: @Ramhound I found [this plugin](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit4/0) but I was hoping for a native solution. Maybe there are other 3rd party alternatives as well.

Comment: [I am sure there are third-party solutions you can run in the background that will sync two calendars.](http://superuser.com/questions/37038/synchronize-outlook-2007-with-google-calendar-using-default-notification-setup?rq=1)   [You would have to find one of those, test it, and decide if it fulfills your requirements.](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this Outlook plugin: [gsyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit4/0), which can sync the events from my Google Calendar to my primary Exchange calendar, effectively creating Busy/Free information on the server.

It's not the best solution, as I have to be logged in and have Outlook opened, but it will work for now until a better solution is suggested.